# Java JTable binding via JPA

Tags: java, swing, jpa, jtable, populate

I have tried to search for proper answers, but nothing helped me so far. I am quite new to java GUI programming, actually, to java itself.. I have however managers to understand JPA, how to retrieve, insert and delete using JPA.

Now I want the data in my database to be shown in a JTable.

I currently have the following mySQL table(which i want to show in a JTable

games
Id PK int
Title
Publisher
Genre
ReleaseDate

As far as coding concerns, I have succesfully retrieved the data contained in the table using the following:

```
public List<Game> getGames(){
    List<Game> games;

    try{
        TypedQuery<Game> selectGamesQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Game g", Game.class);
        games = selectGamesQuery.getResultList();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } 
    return games;
}
```

This succesfully returns a list of games whom I can iterate trough.

Then, in my view I have the following

```
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    tblGames = new JTable(new tblGamesModel());
    tblGames.setShowVerticalLines(true);
    tblGames.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
    tblGames.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(tblGames);
```

Which ofcourse leads us to the table model,which is where I'm stuck.

```
public class tblGamesModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private GameRepository gameRepository;
private List<Game> games;
/**
 * 
 */
public tblGamesModel(){
    gameRepository = new GameRepository();
    games = gameRepository.getGames();
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return games.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    return null;
}
```

}

I know this is alot of code for a simple post, but I really don't know how else to show the current problem. Any good links would help, or advise on its own.

Thanks for taking the time to read the code and possibly help me out.

Remember, I am just a student programming, so I have a lot to learn about conventions etc aswell. So pointers are also welcome, as I am eager to learn from more experienced developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest option is something like this:

```
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 5;
}

...

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Game game = games.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return game.getId();
        case 1:
            return game.getTitle();
        case 2:
            return game.getPublisher();
        case 3:
            return game.getGenre();
        case 4:
            return game.getReleaseDate();
    }
    return null;
}
```

That can be prone to maintenance problems due to all the magic numbers - a solution would be to use an enumeration for the columns:

```
enum GameTableColumn {
    ID, TITLE, PUBLISHER, GENRE, RELEASE_DATE;
}
```

And then get the enumeration instance for a column using GameTableColumn.values()[columnIndex].

A few style notes - tblGamesModel is a non-standard name for a Java class, class names always start with an upper case letter. A more Java name would be GamesTableModel. Hungarian notation prefixes (such as "tbl") are generally discouraged.

Also having a database fetch in a constructor is generally a bad idea. In a Swing application you want all fetches to be explicit so you can ensure they do not block the UI. Rather than getGames() I would suggest retrieveGames(). It may be best to construct the GamesRepository outside the table model and pass it in to the constructor. You could then perform the JPA query first in a different thread. This would prevent the UI thread from freezing while the database access is in progress.

Comment: Thank you very much Russ Hayward, your answer is quite brilliant indeed. I have changed everything you suggested and more, and you are right, the naming convention I used for the table model, did seem a bit off. As for multithreading the query, thanks. I did not  even think about freezing my UI. This problem is also resolved now. The only thing I quite did not understand was the enum part. Doesn't the switch count for all objects in the List<>? And another question, how do I exclude the Id from the list? I can't use it in a query, cause I want to retrieve the ID later on. Thanks again. :)

Comment: aah.. sorry.. I overlooked the getId in the switch. Sorry for this silly question. Figured it all out, and its working. I can sleep safely tonight! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pass loaded list to the model via constructor parameter or setter method. Then you can use following model structure:

```
public class TblGamesModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {"id", "title",
    ...........
    private static final int COL_ID = 0;
    private static final int COL_TITLE = 1;

    private List<Game> list;  //list that is injected via constructor or setter method

    public int getRowCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMNS.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Game game = list.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COL_ID:
                return game.getId();
            ........
        }
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return COLUMNS[column];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. With this comment, and the one above, I have gotten things to work. Thanks again :)

Comment: So , my data is loaded correctly, everything seems fine now, except for the fact that in the switch, the case that returns game.genre is a one to many relationship, ie many games may have one and only one genre, and each genre can have one or more games. How do I select the name of the genre that is in the genre table with 2 columns, Id and Name

Comment: If each game can have only one genre then it is many-to-one between game-genre (game M---1 genre). By default such relationships are fetched eagerly in JPA, so you should be able to do something like `game.getGenre().getName()`. Aren't you?